# How to get the desktop Rect while using ATL?

Tags: c++, atl

I want to get the Rect of the entire desktop from within a dialog, and ATL has overridden the `GetWindowRect(HWND hWnd, LPRECT lpRect)` to `GetWindowRect(LPRECT lpRect)` and it assumes the current dialog window so it just fills the `lpRect` with its own dimensions.

How do I get the desktop window's Rect? I've tried using the `GetDesktopWindow()`, but it returns a `HWND` which with I still can't find the Rect from.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you can do `::GetWindowRect(hWnd, lpRect);` if you want to bypass the ATL's `CWindow::GetWindowRect(LPRECT)` member.

Desktop is not necessarily rectangular as your system might be multi-monitor.

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC444273.png))</sub>

If you ignore the multi-monitor aspect, you can use  [`GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) + `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)` (or `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)` + `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)`), or [`SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) APIs. ATL does not offer any shortcuts, these will have to be direct API calls.

With a multi-monitor system you [enumerate monitors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/enumeration-and-display-control) and get a work area for every enumerated one. Together they are the desktop:

> To enumerate all the devices on the computer, call the `EnumDisplayDevices` function. The information that is returned also indicates which monitor is part of the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I found this snippet on [the MSDN page of CWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d19y607d.aspx) that seems to do what you want:

```
HWND hWnd  = ::GetDesktopWindow();
CWindow myWindow;
myWindow.Attach(hWnd);
```

After this, you should be able to use

```
myWindow.GetWindowRect(lpRect)
```